# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10) (11)

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I m trying to make a function for calculating entropy of an image in python using the PIL module using Dejan Noveski's code.

```
def image_entropy(img):
hgram = np.histogram(img)
histogram_length = sum(hgram)

samples_probability = [float(h) / histogram_length for h in hgram]

return -sum([p * math.log(p, 2) for p in samples_probability if p != 0])
```

It throws the following error

```
 File "test.py", line 45, in <module>
I_e=image_entropy(I)
File "test.py", line 11, in image_entropy
histogram_length = sum(hgram)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1510, in sum
out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 18, in _sum
out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10) (11)
```

I dont understand why its giving broadcast error, because i m not taking any product for that matter, just taking the sum of the matrix. Can somebody help me out.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This code looks very similar to [Dejan Noveski's](http://brainacle.com/calculating-image-entropy-with-python-how-and-why.html).

Comment: Yes, sorry i forgot to mention, its his code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[numpy.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) returns a 2-tuple: the histogram *and* an array of the bin edges. So

```
hgram = np.histogram(img)
```

should be

```
hgram, bin_edges = np.histogram(img)
```

If you use `hgram = np.histogram(img)` then `hgram` gets assigned to the 2-tuple. Python is quite happy to do that; there is no Exception raised there. But when Python evaluates `sum(hist)` it tries to sum the two items in `hist`. One (the histogram values) is an array of length 10, and the other (the bin edges) is an array of length 11. And that is where the ValueError occurs.

---

`np.histogram(img)` expects `img` to be an array. If `img` is a PIL image, then use the [im.histogram method](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm)

```
hgram = img.histogram()
```